# Container traits - is_multi, is_ordered, is_associative

Tags: c++, type-traits

Is there any Trait which tells if container is "multi" or "unordered"?

e.g.

```
is_multi<std::multiset<Foo>>::value_type //true
is_multi<std::set<Foo>>::value_type //false
is_ordered<std::map<Foo, Bar>>::value_type //true
...
```

It is pretty easy to write them (since there are so few containers in stl), but my question is whether there is such call (or some typedef in container) is stl

why?

I'm writing some generic algorithms which works differently on "multi" container (e.g. early out when value found) or on "ordered" containers...

Comment: _"It is pretty easy to write them (since there are so few containers in stl)"_ That's pretty much your answer right there.

Answer (score 1):

I hoped there is some distinguish sign for "multi" and "unordered" containers. For example like all Associative containers contains `key_type` member typedef. It allows to write traits like:

```
template<typename T>
struct to_void
{
    typedef void type;
};

template <typename Container, typename dummy = void>
struct is_associative_container : std::false_type {};

template <typename Container>
struct is_associative_container
<Container, typename to_void<typename Container::key_type>::type > : std::true_type{};
```

I didn't find anything, so I've used enumeration method. So here are container traits:

```
 #include <map>
 #include <set>
 #include <unordered_map>
 #include <unordered_set>

template<typename T>
struct to_void
{
    typedef void type;
};

template <typename Container, typename dummy = void>
struct is_associative_container : std::false_type {};

template <typename Container>
struct is_associative_container<Container, typename to_void<typename Container::key_type>::type > : std::true_type{};

template <typename Container>
struct is_multi_container : std::false_type {};

template <typename Container>
struct is_unique_container : std::conditional<is_multi_container<Container>::value, std::false_type, std::true_type>::type{};

template <typename Container>
struct is_unordered_container : std::false_type {};

template <typename Container>
struct is_ordered_container : std::conditional<is_unordered_container<Container>::value, std::false_type, std::true_type>::type{};

template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Alloc>
struct is_multi_container<std::multiset<T,Compare, Alloc>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Alloc>
struct is_multi_container<std::multimap<T, Compare, Alloc>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename Hash, typename Pred, typename Alloc>
struct is_multi_container<std::unordered_multimap<T, Hash, Pred, Alloc>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename Hash, typename Pred, typename Alloc>
struct is_multi_container<std::unordered_multiset<T, Hash, Pred, Alloc>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename Hash, typename Pred, typename Alloc>
struct is_unordered_container<std::unordered_multimap<T, Hash, Pred, Alloc>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename Hash, typename Pred, typename Alloc>
struct is_unordered_container<std::unordered_map<T, Hash, Pred, Alloc>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename Hash, typename Pred, typename Alloc>
struct is_unordered_container<std::unordered_multiset<T, Hash, Pred, Alloc>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename Hash, typename Pred, typename Alloc>
struct is_unordered_container<std::unordered_set<T, Hash, Pred, Alloc>> : std::true_type{};
```

Comment: of course it would like slightly different when using template aliases, but my compiler doesn't supports them